# Fallo en una query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola alguien me puede decir que falla en la query??

```
$queryCursos = $mysqli->query("SELECT MAX(DATE(Fecha)) Fecha,SUM(PRECIO) Total, idpedido, pdf, factura 
FROM pedidos 
WHERE id_cliente ='$usuario' 
GROUP BY id_cliente, idpedido 
ORDER BY Fecha, id DESC");
```

El error que me devuelve es con el `GROUP BY`

> Errormessage: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause
>   and contains nonaggregated column 'hospital.pedidos.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta debe agrupar por las mismas columnas que tienes en el `SELECT` excepto aquellas que son producto de funciones de agregación.

lo mismo procura incluir en tu `ORDER BY` columnas que tengas en el `SELECT` aquí si pueden ser cuaalquiera de ellas

Entonces deberái verse así:

```
SELECT MAX(DATE(Fecha)) Fecha,
       SUM(PRECIO) Total, 
       idpedido, 
       pdf, 
       factura 
FROM pedidos 
WHERE id_cliente ='$usuario' 
GROUP BY idpedido, pdf, factura 
ORDER BY Fecha DESC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaración!! @BetaM funciono perfecto!